# ASP.NET MVC3 VPS Hosting : Windows 2008 32bit or Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2008, vps

I would like to use a VPS to host my ASP.NET MVC 3 + SQL Server 2008 Express project but I'm hesitating between Windows 2008 and Windows 2008 R2. This server will only have 1 Go of RAM.

I was thinking about choosing Windows 2008 32bit because a 32 bit OS requires less RAM than a 64bit OS but are there some important features of Windows 2008 R2 that I'm going to miss ?Maybe better support for AMS.NET MVC 3, easier deployment ... ?

Comment: your question is better suited for severfault.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to keep the RAM on the VPS under 4GB, I would go with 32bit.  If there is a chance, at all, that you may have 4GB or more of RAM, go 64bit.  The deployment process will be the same for either.  There really isn't a feature difference between the two, other than enabling 64bit support

Answer (score 0):

I would go with windows server 2008 R2.  yes a 32 bit server uses less memory but the improved memory manager in R2 will more then make up for it (the primary focus of R2 was performance improvements), also R2 has a number of IIS upgrades see http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/iis-r2.aspx

your environment is with in R2's spec so I think a better question would be why use just 2008